# Choose sorting order of methods in Eclipse's auto-completion proposals?

Tags: java, eclipse

When I type a `.` after writing an object instance's name, Eclipse shows a list of all methods available for this instance, including methods of superclasses that the object extends.

If I am working with an object implementing some interface, I have to search for the "interesting" methods among the "boring" Object-level methods such as `notify()` or `getClass()`.

Can I have Eclipse sort the methods so that the ones declared in subclasses come first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change sorting:

Go to `Preferences` > `Java` > `Editor` > `Content Assist` > `Sorting and Filtering`.

To filter entries:

Go to `Preferences` > `Java` > `Appearance` > `Type filters`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we don't use autocompletion to study an objects interface. OK, I sometimes do it, like I want to see all getters - but in that case I just type `.get` and have a filtered list.

Usually, autocompletion is used to speed up coding - type the first few letters of a method name (for example) and hit return. And this doesn't even need a sorting. (and if, then I *really* prefer the ascending alphabetically order).

To study the interface, its much better - to my opinion - to take a short break, open the object type in a separate editor and examine the outline view and the java doc.